# Why My Alert Is Not Working After Validation

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

My development environment is in .NET6

At the beginning, it was like this (can be work)

```
function UpdateButton_onClick(srcElement) {
    _alert('ConfirmUpdate');
}
```

But I need to add a verification function to ensure that the content entered by the user meets our needs.

```
function Valid() {
    var result = false;
    var NM = $('#NM').val();
    var regExp = /^[\d|a-zA-Z|\-.]+$/;
    
    if (regExp.test(NM)) {
        result = true;  
    } else {
        result = false; 
    }
    
    if (result == false) {
        _AddJsErrMessage(//resource name//);
        return false;
    } 
     else {
            return true;
    }
```

So, It will be like

```
function UpdateButton_onClick() {
    AddAttrRequired();  //This is a required field for validation
    var Result = _FormValidation(); 
    
    if (Result) {
        if (Valid()) {            
            $.blockUI({ message: '' });            
            $('#ExecAction').val(_ActionTypeUpdate);
            _alert('ConfirmUpdate'); //cannont work
            _formElement.submit();
            return true;
        } else {           
            _ShowJsErrMessageBox();
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        
        return false;
    }  
}
```

please tell me what to do , thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No, the data will be updated and submitted correctly, but I hope to display the alert window before submission

Comment: You can try confirm() method